# Series expansion for $\frac{x}{1- \frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: series-expansion

I would like to expand $\frac{x}{1- \frac{1}{x}}$ as 
$$\frac{x}{1- \frac{1}{x}} = x \left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} +\frac{1}{x^3} + \cdots \right) = x + 1 +  \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}  + \cdots  $$

However, I tried

```
Series[1/(1 - 1/x), {1/x, 0, 2}]
```

it doesn't work

or

```
1/(1 - 1/x) /. 1/x -> t

Series[%, {t, 0, 3}]

% /. t -> 1/x

Expand[x*%]
```

it ends up to

$x \left( 1+ \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2} +\frac{1}{x^3} + \cdots \right) $ cannot be expanded to break the bracket.

How should I do to arrive at $x + 1 +  \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}  + \cdots $?

Comment: You can add `//Normal` after `Series[...]`; however is this an expansion for small or for large `x` ?

Comment: Thank you very much! It works now. The expansion is for large $x$, such that $|1/x| <<1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can expand around infinity as follows:

```
 Series[x/(1 - 1/x), {x, Infinity, 2}]
```

> $x + 1 + \frac{1}{x} + \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2 + \mathcal{O}\left[\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3\right]$

This returns a [`SeriesData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeriesData.html) expression, so you might want to add in a call to `Normal` as [b.gatessucks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/134/b-gatessucks) suggests.